# Remote Commands and Restricted Shells via SSH

Tags: shell, ssh, restricted-shell

I'm working on an ssh server where the only thing I ever want the user doing is

```
ssh user@ip cat somefile
```

Part of my threat mitigation plan was to give the user restricted bash

I've seen examples with `chsh rbash` but on my server rbash was not found. So I made a script "rbash"

```
    #!/bin/bash
    bash -r
```

bash -r is an option to launch the restricted shell, so I put this script in /bin. and ran `chsh user -s /bin/rbash`

Now I can `ssh user@ip` into the server and find myself in a restricted shell, but when I try to `ssh user@ip cat somefile` the ssh process gets stuck at `debug1: sending command: cat somefile`

Am I going about this the right way? When I ssh to login in I can `cat somefile`, how do I make the command work remotely and keep the restricted shell?

Other possibly relevant info

- Os Fedora 29
- ssh auth method public key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create rbash

If you scroll all the way down in the `bash` man page you find the chapter `RESTRICTED SHELL`:

> If  bash  is  started with the name rbash, or the -r option is supplied at invocation, the shell becomes restricted.

To start bash wit the name 'rbash', you could crate a symlink `ln -s /bin/bash /bin/rbash`.

### Restrict user to `cat somefile`

From `man authorized_keys`:

```
command="command"
    Specifies that the command is executed whenever this key is used for
    authentication.
```

You could adjust your authorized_key file:

```
command="cat somefile" KEY_TYPE KEY COMMENT
```

Now this user key combo can only run `cat somefile`.

### Why your wrapper doesn't work

Your script runs `bash -r` and it doesn't execute your command `cat somefile`.
You can see what happens when you put `set -xe` in your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xe
bash -xer
```

That shows that `bash` is not stuck but waiting for input and that you did spawn two shells. It has no prompt but can execute commands:

```
$ ssh user@ip cat somefile
+ /bin/bash -r

ls 
+ ls
somefile
exit
+ exit
exit
+ exit
$
```

You could pipe the command to this shell, but this is not a good solution:

```
ssh user@ip <<< 'cat somefile'
```